# Shortest path cost from all nodes to a particular node in a graph

Tags: c++, algorithm, graph, dijkstra

I am doing a problem in which i have to calculate the total cost of going from one particular node(starting node) to all the rest of the nodes in a **directed** graph and then returning back from these nodes to the starting node.
Now for the first part of the problem i.e going from starting to the rest of the nodes, i have applied dijkstra's algorithm but for the second part, I thought of looping each node as source and using dijkstra's for each node. But, if i am not mistaken, dijkstra calculates path cost from one source node to rest of the nodes which in this case will result in a lot of overhead. All i need for the second part of the problem is the shortest path from all the nodes to one particular node.

Here is what I have been doing(ignore the getchar, that is only for speeding up the input).

```
#include<set>
#include<stdio.h>
#include<vector>
#include<limits.h>
#include<cstdio>
using namespace std;

#define mp make_pair
#define ft first
#define sd second
#define gc getchar

vector< pair<int,int> > g[101000];
int n,m,sum,i,j,k,t,x,y,z;
vector<int> dist;
vector <int> vis;

void scanint(int &x)
{
    register int c = gc();
    x=0;
    for(;(c<48||c>57);c=gc());
    for(;c>47&&c<58;c=gc())
    {
        x=(x<<1)+(x<<3)+c-48;
    }
}
void dijkstra(int source)
{
    dist.clear();
    int i,j,k;
    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        dist.push_back(INT_MAX);
        vis.push_back(0);
    }
    dist[source] = 0;
    set< pair<int,int> > s; // pair is dist, node_number
    set< pair<int,int> >::iterator it;

    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
        s.insert(mp(dist[i],i));

    while(!s.empty())
    {
        it = s.begin();
        pair<int,int> temp = *it;
        s.erase(temp); // remove minimum val node
        int cur = temp.sd;
        int val = temp.ft;

        if(val == INT_MAX)
            return;
        for(i=0;i<g[cur].size();i++)
        {
            int nb = g[cur][i].ft;
            if(!vis[nb] && dist[nb] > val + g[cur][i].sd)
            {
                s.erase(mp(dist[nb],nb)); // erase old val
                dist[nb] = val + g[cur][i].sd;
                s.insert(mp(dist[nb],nb));
            }
        }
    }
    s.clear();

}
int main()
{
   // std::ios::sync_with_stdio(false);
    scanint(t);
    for(int r=0;r<t;r++)
    {
        dist.clear();
        vis.clear();


        scanint(n);
        scanint(m);
        for(i=0;i<m;i++)
            g[i].clear();

        for(i=0;i<m;i++)
        {
            scanint(x);
            scanint(y);
            scanint(z);
            x--;    y--;
            g[x].push_back(mp(y,z));

        }
        dijkstra(0);
        sum=0;
        for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
        sum=sum+dist[i];
        for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
        {
          dijkstra(i);
          sum=sum+dist[0];
        }
        printf("%d\n",sum);
        g[x].clear();
        for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
        {
            dist[i]=INT_MAX;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: In undirectional graph minPath(a,b)=minPath(b,a). So you can just double cost of going from one node to others

Comment: @AlexanderAnikin It is unidirectional not undirectional, the same path cannot be used to trace back.

Comment: @AlexanderAnikin:  Rather depends what you mean by "unidirectional".  I presumed it meant "directed".  In which case your statement is false.  There may not *be* a path from "b" to "a".

Comment: To be honest, I don't know what *uni*directed could mean - it's not canonical. If it's directed graph, my comment is irrelevant to the case, if it's "undirected" or emulation of undirected (when you make two directed edges instead of one undirected), the comment is valid.

Comment: updated unidirectional to directed

Answer (score 3):

You should use a pathfinding algorithm that produces a [shortest-path tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shortest-path_tree). Both Dijkstra's algorithm and the Bellman–Ford algorithm can be used for this. Which of them will perform better will depend on the [density of your graph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dense_graph). For sparse graphs, Dijkstra's algorithm will be faster.

You can then do the following:

1. Calculate the shortest-path tree from your source node. You will now have paths from your source node to all your destinations.
2. Reverse the direction of all edges in the graph, and again calculate the shortest-path tree from your source node. This tree will now contain the shortest paths from your destination nodes to your original source node.